# Python: shortcut for writing decorators which accept arguments?

Tags: python, decorator

Does the Python standard library have a shortcut for writing decorators which accept arguments?

For example, if I want to write a decorator like `with_timeout(timeout)`:

```
@with_timeout(10.0)
def cook_eggs(eggs):
    while not eggs.are_done():
        eggs.cook()
```

I have to write something like:

```
def with_timeout(timeout):
    _func = [None]
    def with_timeout_helper(*args, **kwargs):
        with Timeout(timeout):
            return _func[0](*args, **kwargs)
    def with_timeout_return(f):
        return functools.wraps(f)(with_timeout_helper)
    return with_timeout_return
```

But that's awfully verbose. Is there a shortcut which makes decorators which accept arguments easier to write?

**Note**: I realize that it's also possible to use three nested functions to implement decorators with arguments… But that feels just a bit suboptimal too.

For example, possibly something like a `@decorator_with_arguments` function:

```
@decorator_with_arguments
def timeout(f, timeout):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def timeout_helper(*args, **kwargs):
        with Timeout(timeout):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return timeout_helper
```

Comment: If you need more help with decorators and annotations see my blog post here. http://blog.mattalcock.com/2013/1/5/decorates-and-annotations/

Answer (score 7):

I tend to write my decorators as classes to be honest

```
class TestWithArgs(object):
    def __init__(self, *deco_args, **deco_kwargs):
        self.deco_args = deco_args
        self.deco_kwargs = deco_kwargs
    def __call__(self, func):
        def _wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print "Blah blah blah"
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _wrap
```

Its nothing if not slightly clearer

Answer (score 4):

I know you said it feels suboptimal but I still feel that using three nested models is the cleanest solution. The inner two functions are just the 'normal' way of defining a decorator for a function that takes arguments (see [example](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in python's docs for @wraps). The outer one is really just a function that takes and argument and returns a decorator.

```
def with_timeout(timeout):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with Timeout(timeout):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. There is nothing at all clean about three nested functions (or, for that matter, the way I do it). It's a hack. Better would be, for example, a `@decorator_with_arguments` decorator (see my updated question).

Answer (score 4):

Based on Jakob's suggestion, I've implemented a small `Decorator` class, which I feel does a fairly decent job:

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __call__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        return functools.wraps(f)(lambda *a, **kw: self.wrap(*a, **kw))

    def wrap(self, *args, **kwrags):
        raise NotImplemented("Subclasses of Decorator must implement 'wrap'")

class with_timeout(Decorator):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout

    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with Timeout(timeout):
            return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I fixed a typo on your `with_timeout` method `warp`

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. That's probably the 8th time I've typed 'warp' instead of 'wrap' tonight. And I haven't typed 'wrap' that many times.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can define a little meta-decorator:

```
def decorator_with_arguments(wrapper):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

That allows us to create decorators that accept arguments like so:

```
@decorator_with_arguments
def my_wrapper(func, *decorator_args, **decorator_kwargs):
    def wrapped(*call_args, **call_kwargs):
        print "from decorator:", decorator_args, decorator_kwargs
        func(*call_args, **call_kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Which can then be used normally:

```
@my_wrapper(1, 2, 3)
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print "passed directly:", args, kwargs

test(4, 5, 6)
```

Adding `functools.wraps` decoration is left as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

Another take, without using lambdas:

```
def decorator_with_arguments(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def with_arguments_helper(*args, **kwargs):
        def decorator(g):
            return f(g, *args, **kwargs)
        return decorator
    return with_arguments_helper
```