# In nested classes, how to access outer class's elements from nested class in Python?

Tags: python, class, nested

I have this scenario, where I need to ask a nested class to append items to a list in the outer class. Heres pseudocode thats similar to what Im trying to do. How would I go about getting it to work?

```
class Outer(object):
  outerlist = []
  class Inner(object):
    def __call__(self, arg1):
      outerlist.append(arg1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  f = Outer()
  f.Inner("apple")
  f.Inner("orange")

  print f.outerlist()
```

This is what I hope to see -  `apple, orange`

Details:
OS X, Python 2.7

Comment: Why would you use a nested classes *at all*?

Comment: So Im trying to have the Outer class contain decorators that will accept arguments, and the best way to do that is to have decorators written as classes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610824/python-shortcut-for-writing-decorators-which-accept-arguments

Comment: Yes, using a class for a decorator is a good idea, but that doesn't mean you need to use *nested* classes. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @sri: Yes, the decorators should be a class, I agree. But the class you decorate should be a completely separate class. No nesting.

Comment: Some side issues: I assume you want `print f.outerlist`, not `f.outerlist()`, because you can't call a `list`. Also, while you're allowed to access class variables via an instance, it's usually less confusing to access them by the class, as in `print Outer.outerlist`. (And the fact that you're accessing it via `f` means I have to ask: do you actually want a class variable here?)

Comment: Also, `Inner.__call__` is called every time you try to use a constructed instance of `Inner` as a function, not when you try to construct one (= when you try to use the class as a function, loosely speaking), so you're going to need `Inner()("apple")`, not `Inner("apple")` here. If you want to change that, you need to override `__init__` instead. Or, as Sheena suggests, just override `__new__` to interrupt the normal object creation/initialization, because you have no need for the `Inner` objects you're creating.

Comment: @abarnert , @MartijnPieters, @LennartRegebro - (Bear with me here) - Heres what Im trying to do. (For ref heres some pseudo code - http://pastebin.com/m8AxB4ey ). So my intention is to have a list in the ``Outer`` class that will collect all the ``url``ish arguments passed to the decorators there, so Outer can process them and run them when "``__call__``" ed. I am not able to see a clean way to remove the decorator classes from nesting inside ``Outer``, but Im totally open to ideas. Really appreciate your input,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand your design, you're going about things all wrong.

First, Outer is a class; it doesn't get `__call__`ed. Your line 17 is just going to construct an empty `Outer` object and do nothing with it. If you want to "call" the `Outer` object, you can define an `__init__` method—or, as Sheena suggests, define a `__new__` and intercept the initialization, since you don't actually need the initialized object anyway.

Honestly, I don't think someone who doesn't understand how `__call__` works yet should be trying to build something tricky like this yet. But if you insist, read on.

It's a very odd, and probably bad, design to collect this kind of stuff in a class instead of an instance. Keep in mind that class variables are effectively globals, with all that entails. If you try to use `Outer` reentrantly, or from multiple threads/event handlers/greenlets/whatever, the uses will end up stomping all over each other. Even if you think that isn't possibly going to be a problem now, it likely will at some point in the future.

You could create an `Outer` instance, and use its members as decorators. For example:

```
from outer_library import Outer

outer = Outer()

@outer.get("/")
…
```

But I'm not sure that's much better. The entire design here seems to involve performing actions at the module level, even though it looks like you're just defining normal functions and calling a function at the end. The fact that you've managed to confuse yourself should be evidence of how confusing a design this is.

But if you *do* want to do that, what you probably want to do is define classes inside the `Outer.__init__` method, and assign them to instance members. Classes are first-class values, and can be assigned to variables just like any other values. Then, use the `__init__` (or `__new__`) methods of those classes to do the work you wanted, making the classes simulate functions.

This may seem confusing or misleading. But remember that the whole point of what you're trying to do is to use a class in a way that it looks like a method, so that kind of confusion is inherent in the problem. But if you prefer, you can write decorators as functions (in this case, as normal instance methods of `Outer`); it just makes a different part of the problem harder instead of this part.

A more normal way to design something like this would be to make `Outer` a perfectly normal class that people can either subclass or create instances of, and provide an explicit non-fancy way to attach handler methods or functions to URLs. Then, once that's working, design a way to simplify that handler registration with a decorator.

Comment: Point taken. (the pastebin code is wrong in the ``__main__`` part - my bad,)I am not supposed to talk about my project online atm and  but suffice to say, it is supposed to be a singleton and should be callable, it is instantiated properly in my code. Sorry about not being able to word things clearer, Il work on that the next time. But atleast as far as my question goes its been answered. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

This will have the desired result.

Notice the use of `__new__` (line A). This means that instead of doing any construction stuff properly Inner just appends the list. Also, to access class properties of a containing class just use the outer class's name (line B).

Lastly see line C. the list is not a function. You had some extra brackets in your original code.

```
class Outer(object):
    outerlist = []
    class Inner(object):
        def __new__(self, arg1):                #A
            Outer.outerlist.append(arg1)        #B

f = Outer()
f.Inner("apple")
f.Inner("orange")
print f.outerlist                               #C
```

Comment: So is ``__new__`` called everytime it does ``__init__`` or ``__call__`` ? Thats pretty neat.

Comment: @sri: Not every time it does a `__call__`—that's an instance method, which can be called multiple times. It's called once, when the class needs to create an instance—generally, right before `__init__`.

Comment: @Sheena: They're "class variables". The word "static" refers to things that are associated with neither the class nor the instance, and "properties" are a special kind of class variable whose descriptor lets them acts like an instance variable. But otherwise, all on the money.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access the outer class with the full global name:

```
class Outer(object):
    outerlist = []
    class Inner(object):
        def __call__(self, arg1):
            Outer.outerlist.append(arg1)
```

In python, there generally is no need to nest classes in any case. There are use-cases where it makes sense to define a class in a function (to use scoped variabels), but rarely is there a need for nested classes.

Comment: This is mostly right, but using `__call__` means you have to write `Outer.Inner()("apple")` rather than just `Outer.Inner("apple")`. The mistake is in the OP's code, not yours, but it still needs to be corrected.

Comment: @abarnert: the OP hardly knows what needs to be achieved, so I'll postpone talking about how to call this until it is clear what the real goal is..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Excuse me. I have a restless pet in my hands -hence the delay and this involves homework - hence the vagueness. I did reply to your comment under the question. Please check. I would be more than happy to explain further. Thanks.

Comment: @sri: If this involves homework, can you tell us what part of this is the assignment, and what part you thought up yourself? It seems likely to me that there's a much simpler and more pythonic way to build what your teacher wanted. (That's not guaranteed—after all, some teachers are insane… But it's worth checking.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass in the outer class instance as a parameter to the inner class method? You can access the members of the outer class instance that way.

```
  class Outer(object):
    outerlist = []
    class Inner(object):
      def __init__(self, outer_self):
        self.outer = outer_self
      def __call__(self, arg1):
        self.outer.outerlist.append(arg1)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
   f = Outer()
   i = f.Inner(f)
   i("apple")
   i("orange")

   print f.outerlist
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the option pointed out by picmate (passing the outer class as an input of the inner one) is a good choice for this particular problem. Note that it could also work without having to 'nest' the classes (in my opinion, something to avoid here since it is unnecessary). Note that I have also embedded the initialization of the inner class inside the outer one (this step is not strictly needed, but I include it here for illustrative purposes):

```
class Outer(object):
  outerlist = []
  def __init__(self):
    self.Inner=Inner(Outer=self)
  def get_basket(self):
    print "Outer basket: %s" %(self.outerlist)

class Inner(object):
  def __init__(self,Outer):
    self.Outer=Outer
  def __call__(self, arg1):
    self.Outer.outerlist.append(arg1)
  def get_basket(self):
    print "Inner basket: %s" %(self.Outer.outerlist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  f = Outer()
  print "Initial state"
  f.get_basket()
  f.Inner.get_basket()
  f.Inner("apple")
  f.Inner("orange")
  print "Final state"
  f.get_basket()
  f.Inner.get_basket()
```